# TabControl with browser

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I am trying to add new tabs to my control using a button, when it adds it I want to auto add a browser to it. Was wondering would making  anew browser for each tab be bad or would I just delete the browser if I leave a tab and add it if I click on a tab?

When I click my button so far it adds a new tab but no browser is added. Thanks for       any help!

```
        String title = "List " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        WebBrowser Browser = new WebBrowser();
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(title);
        tabControl1.SelectTab(tabControl1.TabCount-1);
        //Browser.Name = "Web Browser";
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser);
```

Comment: `WebBrowser`s are expensive, you'll have to think about how to trim down number of webbrowsers

Comment: Could I add and remove based on click of tab, so if I click a different tab the browser is removed from where it was and added to the new one? or would that be too slow and noticable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a browser is definitely getting added.  It will be hard to see since you don't load any document in the browser, it just looks the same as a completely empty TabPage.  Arbitrarily add this line to have something to look at:

```
  Browser.DocumentText = title;
```

Get ahead by adding the code to set the browser's Url property so it will load a real web page.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up noticing the colour was slightly off. 
Just on a side note how can I add an array to each individual tab and be able to access them?